# How to verify an exe/dll/sys is original from Microsoft?

Tags: winapi, digital-signature, capicom

I need some *easy* API to verify that a PE file is valid & Microsoft signed just like [SignTool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387764(VS.85).aspx). Where should I start? Could this be done with CAPICOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example C Program: Verifying the Signature of a PE File:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382384(VS.85).aspx